# prevent mariadb / phpmyadmin from having same value on 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

how to do this on the database side on phpmyadmin? I've seen about check and trigger but still can't figure it out.

| ID | Point A | Point B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Z |
| 2 | X | Z |
| 3 | X | X |

1 -> Allowed

2 -> Disallowed. Because already have the same data

3 -> Disallowed. Because point A = Point B

Comment: Add a [check constraint](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints)

Comment: @danblack ive read about it but still, I dont know what to type in the query

Answer (score 1):

1. To avoid double values, you have to define an UNIQUE INDEX on columns point_a and point_b.
2. To disallow same values for point_a and point_b you have to specify a check constraint which checks if point_a and point_b differ.

   CREATE TABLE your_table(id unsigned int not null primary key,
   point_a int,
   point_b int,
   UNIQUE INDEX(point_a, point_b),
   CHECK(point_a != point_b));